# Is there any function for find white spaces?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need a function that find white spaces in plsql in a string for example "Hi world, this is my string"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use regular expressions, i.e. `REGEXP_INSTR`. Here's an example; `POS` represents position of a space.

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'Hi world, this is my string' from dual)
  3  select regexp_instr(col, ' ', 1, level) pos
  4  from test
  5  connect by level <= regexp_count(col, ' ');

       POS
----------
         3
        10
        15
        18
        21

SQL>
```

To verify the result:

```
Hi world, this is my string
  *      *    *  *  *
123456789012345678901234567
  3      10   15 18 21
```